# How to open div smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pls help me how to open div smoothly.I have add script and html code, its working perfectly but div open suddenly with jerk. I want to open my div "#mapsec" smoothly.

```
function showhide() {
    var div = document.getElementById("mapsec");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "block";

    }
}
```

## HTML CODE

```
<h3>Visit us (<i><a onclick="showhide()" id="scrollmap" class="mapimg" style="cursor: pointer;">Map</a></i>)</h3>

<div id="mapsec" style="display: none; clear: both;">
    <img
        src="http://www.websitesnmore.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/map-img.jpg"
        alt="map-img" width="1245" height="350"
        class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4586" />
</div>
```

Comment: use css3 transitions instead of jQuery/Javascript animation

Answer (score 5):

You have several ways to do it with jQuery. For example:

```
function showhide() {

    $('#mapsec').slideToggle(200);
}
```

This will slide the div open or closed. 200 is the speed of the animation in miliseconds.

Check these out:

1. `$('#mapsec').toggle(200);` — [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
2. `$('#mapsec').slideToggle(200);` — [jQuery.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)
3. `$('#mapsec').fadeToggle(200);` — [jQuery.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

Comment: Ok I know I'm usually a little late to know THIS kind of easy things after I have spent over hours to figure out the same effect. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Using `display` does exactly what it says it does: `display`or `hide` elements. You could use jQuerys `hide` and `show` functions, but since you are trying to use standard javascript, I'll hand you another solution:

```
<div id="mapsec">
<!-- Your Contents -->
</div>
```

Now your CSS:

```
#mapsec { 
    max-height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    /* You should prefix the following: */
    transition: max-height 500ms;
}
#mapsec.active {
    /* Depending on this value, your animatiom will seem faster or shorter */
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Now the javascript:

```
function showhide(){
    var div = document.getElementById("mapsec");
    if (div.className === "") {
        div.className = "active";
    } else {
        div.className = "";
    }
}
```

What we are using is CSS3's built-in animations to trigger something that looks smoother. We hide the `overflow` of the box you want to animate - as you want it to be invisible. Then we also set it `max-height` to `0`, so it will appear to have no `height` whatsoever (I would like to add that any `padding`s and `margin`s don't get included here and might need to be reset as well).

Now we simple add the `active` class to the div to animate it.

Heres an improved, more universal, and reusable version of the CSS and javascript:

```
<div id="mapsec" class="hidden">
<!-- Your Contents -->
</div>

.hidden { 
    max-height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    transition: max-height 500ms;
}
.hidden.active {
    max-height: 1000px;
}

function showhide(id){
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div.className === "hidden") {
        div.className = "hidden  active";
    } else {
        div.className = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Now you can add `hidden` to any box and unhide it by doing `<a href="#" onclick="showHide('id'); return false;">Unhide</a>`(replacing `'id'` with the `id` of the element you want to show).

If you want to use jQuery, we can make it even better and easier (and robuster) by using something `jQuery` has built-in:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#mapsec').toggleClass('active'); return false;">Unhide</a>
```

Now the `toggleClass` will add the `active` class and remove it by itself! This is better, as when you use multiple classes, jQuery will leave them intact (notice we don't actually have to use `hidden` in this code anymore? As long as it already has `hidden`, we can leave it alone.)

```js
function showhide(id){
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div.className === "hidden") {
        div.className = "hidden  active";
    } else {
        div.className = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden { 
    max-height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    /* You should prefix the following: */
    transition: max-height 500ms;
}
.hidden.active {
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mapsec" class="hidden">
   <img src="" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:showhide('mapsec')">ShowHide</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jQuery.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
function showhide() {
    $('#mapsec').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#mapsec" ).show( "slow" );
```

This should ease the div in nicely instead of:

```
div.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would mainly agree with [somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere), but since you animate a div with an image inside, than I would animate height of div and set the image height to 100%. Think that looks better/smoother [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdL8maym/1/). JS changing class is from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236608/how-to-open-div-smoothly#answer-28236691), but CSS is:

```
#mapsec {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 500ms;
    transition: height 500ms;
}
#mapsec.active {
    height: 200px;
}
#mapsec img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This solution is not as good as you **hardcode** the height of the div. Using `max-height` like in my solution will allow the div to scale to its intended size (as long as its smaller than 2000px in height), which means you can easily reuse the code. Now, I'll admit that 2000px might be a bit much (so the animation seems almost instantaneous), but it does work and is scalable.

Comment: You are right 100%. Just specially in his case I would sacrifice universality for beauty.

Comment: True, but the only problem is that if this site would be responsive, the height of the image might change depending on the width. I find it prettier if boxes don't have a bunch of whitespace at the bottom because the height is hardcoded. But thats just me. I do agree, don't get me wrong.

Comment: You can see [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/LdL8maym/3/) a responsive version based on image ratio.